# is "a handful of" use as adjective in the context?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

'this is one of a handful of songs'

dictionary defines 'handful' as a noun,but some blog define 'a handful of' as a quantity adjective, it is hard to understand..can someone explain to me? thanks!

Comment: _A handful of_ literally means 'only as many/much as you can hold in one hand' (imagine a handful of pebbles or sand). It's used figuratively to mean a small number of things you can't physically hold.

Comment: It should be easy to see the syntax of ***a handful of*** if you just think in terms of replacing it by an actual ***number*** (which I assume you're happy to call a "quantity adjective"). For example, *This is one of **ten** songs [on the new album].* Obviously ***a handful of*** and ***ten*** have identical syntactic roles there.

Comment: As BillJ says in his answer, it is a "partitive" construction. In earlier forms of English that preserved case declensions, it was known as a "partitive genitive" construction. Compare: "This pair is **one of a roomful of shoes** owned by the president's wife." or "The Lamborghini was but **one of a garageful of cars** owned by the popular comedian."

Comment: We,sometimes, use *of* after words or phrases expressing amount, number or a particular unit(after Preposition a Noun or pronoun or it's equivalents are used, so for this *handful* should be a Noun(a handful of songs=a small number of songs)(one of a handful of songs=One that belongs to a small number of songs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This is* [*one of a handful of songs*].

"A handful of" is not adjectival; in fact it is not a constituent, not a single grammatical unit.

The bracketed element is a partitive construction in that the head word "one" is followed by the partitive *PP complement "of a handful of songs".

The noun phrase, "one of a handful of songs", is partitive in the sense that it denotes a subset of the set consisting of "a handful of songs".

We understand it to mean "one song from the set of a handful of songs".

*preposition phrase

Answer (score 2):

*Handful* **is** a noun. Consider “Do you enjoy pretzels? Take a handful” or “That misbehaved child is a real handful.”

*A handful of* means something like several or a few. Consider “Because of the rain, we got only a handful of trick-or-treaters.”